# Downloading a magnetic link with Powershell 3

Tags: powershell, download, powershell-3.0, utorrent, magnet-uri

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to create a short script that will find magnetic links on a page and download them.

I don't have much of an understanding of how magnetic URIs work and I can't seem to get my script to download files via them.

I am using the following code snippet:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:44bb5e0325b7dad0bdc5abce459b85b014766ec0&dn=MY_TORRENT&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp"

$file = "C:\Some\Path\myfile.torrent"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url, $file)
```

Which produces the following exception

```
    System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." ---> System.Net.We
bException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception exception, Type typeToThrow, String methodName, Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo member
Info)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Is there a different way of downloading in PowerShell or is this not possible with a magnetic link.

My ultimate goal is to start downloading a torrent via a magnetic link, so maybe it's possible to just open a torrent client with the link, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a torrent client like `µTorrent` installed and it is set to handle magnet links, you can just open the link from Powershell:

```
start "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:44bb5e0325b7dad0bdc5abce459b85b014766ec0&dn=MY_TORRENT&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp"
```

That should open the torrent client.

You can also use a command line torrent client [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/%5d) and download:

```
aria2c "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:44bb5e0325b7dad0bdc5abce459b85b014766ec0&dn=MY_TORRENT&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Magnetic links](http://lifehacker.com/5875899/what-are-magnet-links-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-download-torrents) use a protocol `magnet` not natively supported by Windows, and not supported by `DownloadFile()`.

If you install a client that does support the `magnet` protocol, it will install a [protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `magnet` URI Scheme.

That should allow you to use `Start-Process`, passing just the magnetic URL as an argument, to invoke that client and have it do whatever processing it normally does with that URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have a github project ([FirefoxMagnetMimeHandler](https://github.com/jpmikkers/FirefoxMagnetMimeHandler)) shows how to send a magnet link to a local or remote transmission server via the transmission [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/master/extras/rpc-spec.txt) using powershell. In essence this comes down to sending small chunks of JSON to the transmission server. The difficult part is getting a correct session ID.

Here's a link to the relevant script: [magnet_add.ps1](https://github.com/jpmikkers/FirefoxMagnetMimeHandler/blob/master/mimehandler/magnet_add.ps1) . The other scripts only deal with setting up firefox mime handlers.